# Rails: remove port from _url helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, thin

When calling the _url helper in rails it will return host+port+path so for example

```
photo_url
```

will return

```
http://localhost:3000/photo
```

In my production environment I have thin serving the rails application on a given port and apache serving static content on another port. When the site is accesed without any port each server knows wich part to handle and everything is fine. However if a specific port is given, only the requested server sends a response (which is expected).

I'm now running into troubles, because when I authenticate a user via oauth2 (facebook, twitter) oder openid I need to send an callback url. The gem I use (OmniAuth) uses the _url helper (as far as I can tell) (callback_url) to calculate the callback url. Which results in only thin responding to further requests because of the appended port number.

Is there a way to tell rails, that it is not running on any specific port? Or that it does not use the portnumber in the _url helper?

Answer (score 1):

OmniAuth does *not* use a helper, but rather uses its own method which parses `request.url` to calculate the full path unless you provide configuration yourself.

OmniAuth's [`callback_url`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/oa-oauth/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb#L51-53):

```
def callback_url
  full_host + callback_path
end
```

OmniAuth's [`full_host`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L360) :

```
def full_host
  case OmniAuth.config.full_host
    when String
      OmniAuth.config.full_host
    when Proc
      OmniAuth.config.full_host.call(env)
    else
      uri = URI.parse(request.url)
      uri.path = ''
      uri.query = nil
      uri.to_s
  end
end
```

So, if you access the page on `http://localhost:3000/whatever`, OmniAuth will use `http://localhost:3000` as the `full_url`. If the page is accessed on `http://mysite.com/whatever`, the `full_url` will be `http://mysite.com`. Thus, the port number of the `thin` server serving the page *should not* be appended to the URL, unless the URL used to access the page that redirects the user to the callback includes the port number.

Note that, if necessary, you can configure OmniAuth to use a fixed `full_host` by setting `OmniAuth.config.full_host` to a `String` or `Proc` that returns the value you want to use.

Comment: The links for callback_url and full_host are returning 404. Can you please update them?

Comment: I think we'll need to overwrite the realm also.

Comment: You may be able to override the realm this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032249/omniauth-and-open-id-with-google-broken-when-running-behind-nginx-in-ssl-mode/10187892#10187892 (still did not work for me, but at least I get compatible callback and realm, so the provider doesn't complain)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use photo_path instead?

Comment: I would need to change the gem for that, which would not be a nice solution. (The behaviour of the gem is correct, it's my setup that's strange)