# Omniauth and open_id with Google broken when running behind nginx in SSL mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, openid, omniauth

Rails 3.0.12, newest omniauth, I can connect to Google and get the user's email address just fine. But then I run that same rails app behind nginx in SSL mode, and it fails with the Google page:

```
"The page you requested is invalid."
```

**Is it my nginx config? My omniauth setup?**

I know the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` is the special sauce here, is there anything else I need to do to get openid happy behind an SSL web server?

Here's the full example code: you can clone this repo, `bundle install`, and run `rails s` to see it work just fine, then run `rake server` to see it fail.
https://github.com/jjulian/open_id_ssl

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  2;
pid        tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log  log/error.log;
daemon     off;

events {
}

http {
  client_body_temp_path tmp/body;
  proxy_temp_path       tmp/proxy;
  fastcgi_temp_path     tmp/fastcgi;
  uwsgi_temp_path       tmp/uwsgi;
  scgi_temp_path        tmp/scgi;

  server {
    listen 3000 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      development.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  development.key;
    ssl_verify_depth     6;

    access_log log/access.log;
    proxy_buffering off;
    location / {
      proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3300;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
      proxy_redirect    off;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
  }
}
```

omniauth.rb initializer:

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :open_id, :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
end
```

routes.rb:

```
OpenIdSsl::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/auth/open_id/callback' => 'accounts#update'
  match '/auth/failure' => 'accounts#failure'
  root :to => 'accounts#show'
end
```

**UPDATE:** This example used Rails 3.1.12 and OmniAuth 1.0.3. Upgrading to Rails 3.1.4 and OmniAuth 1.1.0 fixes the issue.

Comment: Are you sure google does not hit your server ? if you are using a test certificate maybe google refuses to use it. I would run a tcpdump to check if any connection attempt is made before going further.

Comment: Google never "hits" the local server - the app generates a browser redirect to an invalid url. Try the example code I posted, it runs right out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your problem, I am still trying to find something cleaner but here is the quick & dirty fix:

add this in your config/initializers/omniauth.rb:

```
class Rack::OpenID
  def realm_url(req)
    'https://localhost:3000'
  end
end
```

And now for the explanation: when the rack-openid gem builds the request to send to the google openid server it fails in one spot using the rails application access url and not the nginx one (wich uses ssl) resulting in this being sent to the openid server:

```
openid.realm:http://localhost:3001
openid.return_to:https://localhost:3001/auth/open_id/callback
```

The realm use the http url (rails url) while the return_to points to the right https url (nginx), when the openid server sees this it stops and return an error.

PS: I will edit the answer if I manage to find a cleaner way.

Comment: Your answer got me digging deeper into the Rack and OmniAuth code, and after seeing the REQUEST_URI being "http" during the request phase, I dug into the Rails code. That got me to try Rails 3.1 (my example was 3.0) and along with upgrading to OmniAuth 1.1.0, It's all fixed! You get the bounty - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: looks like I was a little late for the bounty but I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to configure your google app callback URL to add https instead of http.

I have multiple apps setup one for testing with `rails s` and another staging deployment and another for when I deploy to production.

Comment: Try running the server - https://github.com/jjulian/open_id_ssl Google never even gets to call back my app, it constructs an invalid initial url.